# how to get values for multidimensional array from user in node/javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

getting values for a multidimensional array from users in C programming, we can use two for loops and scanf to get values.When I tried that in similar way in node javascript attempt was failed

I have tried something like this:

```
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync')
var arr = new Array();

console.log('enter aray values');

for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++){
       
 arr[i][j] = readlineSync.questionInt('')
   
 }

}

console.log(arr);
```

and I got an error saying :

```
arr[i][j] = readlineSync.questionInt('')
                  ^
TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't set properties on undefined.

```
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync')
var arr = new Array();

console.log('enter aray values');

for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        arr[i] = [];
        arr[i][j] = readlineSync.questionInt('')
    }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error describes that `arr[i]` is `undefined`, which means that no properties can be set on it.

Each dimension of the multidimensional array should be created in each iteration of the loop:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    //  initialize the dimension as an empty array
    arr[i] = new Array();
    for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = readlineSync.questionInt('')
    }
}
```